# ejabberd with sql support after installation

Tags: ejabberd

I have been using ejabberd with Mnesia for past 2 months. Now I wanted to add mysql database. 
I have a confusion here. I installed ejabberd from source using this line

`./configure --enable-user --prefix=/tmp/eja1809`

Now I found that for using ejabberd with mysql I need to compile the ejabberd using the same `./configure` option as

`./configure --enable-mysql`.

So my question is that do I need to use `--enable-user` again like this

`./configure --enable-user --enable-mysql --prefix=/tmp/eja1809`

or is there no need to add enable user again, to add mysql to ejabberd which has already been installed.

Also Do I need to use both make and make install after using the ./configure statement ?

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is that do I need to use --enable-user again like this
>   `./configure --enable-user --enable-mysql --prefix=/tmp/eja1809`

That's correct: provide in ./configure all the options you want it to use, because it takes in consideration only the options you provide now, it doesn't remember what you provided in previous calls, neither months or minutes ago :)

> Also Do I need to use both make and make install after using the
>   ./configure statement ?

Right, compilation includes configure and make, then you must install it. For example, when I'm testing changes in ejabberd source code, I run all of this:

```
./configure --enable-user --enable-odbc --enable-mysql --enable-tools
./rebar get-deps
./rebar update-deps
./rebar compile
make
sudo make install 
ejabberdctl live
```